# merged dataframe failing to join by id after return from function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called order_df:

```
id      count   created_at  group_field type
5753    -1300   2020-11-24  3d74a       new
f12a    -1      2020-11-26  4fa87       new
cf01    -1      2020-11-27  ce13d       new
0b19    -1      2020-11-30  551de       new
1512    -1      2020-11-30  476ea       new
7d07    -1      2020-11-30  79a27       new
3b5e    -195    2020-12-03  f3dba       new
```

which I am trying to merge with cids_df:

```
group_field identifer
3d74a       adc
4fa87       vbr
ce13d       add
551de       bg2
476ea       ggb3
79a27       dd2d
f3dba       f4ef
```

This is my code:

```
def get_ids(request_type, unique_id):
    if request_type == 'order':
        list_to_string_id = str(unique_id)[1:-1]
        query = 'select ocr.id as '"group_field"', o.identifier from outlet o inner join ' + request_type + ' ocr on ocr.unique_id=o.unique_id where ocr.id in('+list_to_string_id+');'
        outlet_df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
        return outlet_df

df['group_field'] = df['r_id'].str.extract('(?P<outlet_id>/outlet_id/.+)')
if df['group_field'].any():
    request_type = 'order'
    order_df = main.copy()
    order_df = order_df[order_cancel_df['group_field'].notna()]
    order_df['group_field'] = order_df['id'].str.extract('oulet_id/(.+?)$')
    unique_id = order_df['group_field'].dropna().tolist()
    cids_df = get_ids(request_type, unique_id)
    order_df = pd.merge(order_df, cids_df, on='group_field', how='outer')
```

I'm looking to do an outer join just in case `cids` comes up with more values than `order_df`. When I merge the two dataframes I am getting this output:

```
id      count   created_at  group_field type    identifier
5753    -1300   11/24/20    3d74a       new 
f12a    -1      2020-11-26  4fa87       new 
cf01    -1      2020-11-27  ce13d       new 
0b19    -1      2020-11-30  551de       new 
1512    -1      2020-11-30  476ea       new 
7d07    -1      2020-11-30  79a27       new 
3b5e    -195    2020-11-22  f3dba       new 
                            3d74a               adc
                            4fa87               vbr
                            ce13d               add
                            551de               bg2
                            476ea               ggb3
                            79a27               dd2d
                            f3dba               f4ef
```

I would expect the join to merge on group_field but instead it's just stacking the two dataframes together.

Is there a better method to joining the two dataframes together beside using merge?

Comment: Could you check `cids_df.group_field.values` and `order_df.group_field.values` and see if both id matches exactly?  make sure there is no trailing spaces?

Comment: interestingly enough the cids_df are being returned as  [UUID('uudi-vales-here') [UUID('uudi-vales-here')]. So it's not a string which I need to use to join. Any idea on how to turn this into a string and join properly? @Emma

Comment: You can try `cids_df['group_field'] = cids_df.group_field.astype(str)`

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! I was banging my head on that one a bit.

Comment: Awesome.  glad to hear.